# Consolidating google results for 2 domains with the same content

Tags: seo, google-search-console, multiple-domains

I have 2 domains `http://foo.com` and a `http://bar.com`. `http://bar.com` is just a domain alias for `http://foo.com` so they have the same content. Results for both domains show up on google, I'd rather all google results point to `http://foo.com`. I've tried looking for this option in google webmaster tools but can't find it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Webmaster Tools does not have any functionality for this.

You can use [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to tell Google which is the preferred domain.

Comment: I'd rather not redirect. Half of my users specifically prefer using foo.com and the other half likes using bar.com. I'm using IIS 7.5

Comment: I've changed my answer to reflect this

Comment: oh yeah, I remember seeing the cross domain canonical a while back, just wasn't able to add that to my site at the time. I think that should work for me ok now. thanks